# Some confusion in conversation, need clarification

Tags: meaning-in-context

I applied for a job today (online). The conversation I had with HR is below.

Me:

> Since I'm from India so could you please let me know whether you'll be
>   providing H1B-Visa or not?

HR:

> This position does not merit an H-1B. The job requires training in the
>   US for about 2.5 months and then deployment to Antarctica. When we
>   have an international hire we get a short term J-1 visa for the
>   training period only. There is no visa requirement for Antarctica.

I'm not getting him completely. Does the above means I am allowed to get training in US or I must have a VISA which they are not ready to provide?

Comment: The way I read it, HR is saying you don't need an H-1B, just a J-1 which they will get for you. I wouldn't stake my future on that, so be sure to get them to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read this to mean that they intend to procure a J-1 visa for international applications as the time spent training in the US is not long enough to require a H1B.  You will not need a visa for Antarctica, as it is not a territory of another country.